Doubts about the Receiver in GO Language Interface Assertion
type Tt struct {
    fmt.Stringer

    I int
    J string
}

func (t *Tt) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Tt{I:%d, J:%s}", t.I, t.J)
}

func main() {
    t := Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"}

    fmt.Printf("%t", true)
    var i any = t
    v, ok := i.(fmt.Stringer)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("t --> %s", v)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("t --> null")
    }
}

If the address of t is assigned to i, the true branch can be executed normally. Does the interface assertion of Go language distinguish whether the receiver is of pointer type? But the interface definition ignores the receiver, which is a bit strange. ////go version go1.22.2 windows/amd64

In this statement:
var i any = t

the value t is assigned to i.  The dynamic type of i is Tt. (If you dig into the implementation, you will find that i contains a pointer to a copy of t and not the copy of t directly.)
The type assertion v, ok := i.(fmt.Stringer) fails because type dynamic type Tt does not have a String() string method in it's method set.
The type *Tt has a String() string method, but the value in i is a Tt, not a *Tt.

Does the interface assertion of Go language distinguish whether the receiver is of pointer type?

The type assertion considers the method set of the dynamic type in the interface.  Pointer vs. value determines which methods are in the method set as described here, but that's not a direct consideration of the type assertion.
The (*Tt).String() string method hides the String() string method promoted from the  fmt.Stringer field. As a result, that field does nothing and is probably not doing what you think it's doing.

(1) May you know it but I inform it. Your Tt embed fmt.Stringer interface but it doesn't mean Tt implements fmt.Stringer. It will be helpful to clarify why you add fmt.Stringer as embedded member at Tt.
(2)
Yes, Go distinguishes the receiver of the pointer and values.
Effective_go#pointers_vs_values

The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be invoked on pointers.
...


This rule arises because pointer methods can modify the receiver; invoking them on a value would cause the method to receive a copy of the value, so any modifications would be discarded.

You declared your method with pointer receiver. So you need to use t := &Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"} for using the receiver.
Or, you can use the value receiver with t := Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"} for implementing fmt.Stringer. In this time, you can also use t := &Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"}
package main

import "fmt"

type Tt struct {
    fmt.Stringer

    I int
    J string
}

func (t Tt) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Tt{I:%d, J:%s}", t.I, t.J)
}

func main() {
    t := Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"}
    // t := &Tt{I: 100, J: "abc"} // is also possible

    fmt.Printf("%t", true)
    var i any = t
    v, ok := i.(fmt.Stringer)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("t --> %s", v)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("t --> null")
    }
}


